# Not able to perform AJAX call for MVC contoller

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I just want to use ajax call for my Spring MVC controller but Ajax call not hitting to the controller's method. Am I doing it wrong?

My Jsp Code [ModifyUser.jsp]:

```
<form name="testForm" >
<table>
<tr><th>User ID</th><td><input id="user_id"  type="text" value="AD001" 
readonly="readonly"> </td></tr>
<tr><th>Name</th><td><input id="user_name"  type="text" value="ABC SBC "> 
</td></tr>
<tr><th>E-mail</th><td><input id="user_email" type="text" 
value="asd@xyz.com"> </td></tr>
</table>
<form>
<script>
function deleteUser()
{ 
    alert("going to delete user");
 $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteUserReq",
    data : {
    "usrId" : ${user_id}
    },
    success: function(data){
    //response from controller
         alert(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

My Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("deleteUserReq")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView inactiveUserReq(@RequestParam HttpServletRequest 
request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
System.out.println("===== going to delete user ===== ");
/*String userChk=reportDAOImpl.inactiveUser(userID);*/
String userChk="success";
System.out.println("  ===  "+userChk);
return new ModelAndView("ModifyUser","responsetxt",userChk);

}
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/deleteUserReq")` does that create any difference?

Comment: not working @Shubh Dixit

Answer (score 0):

> you should not return model and view with response body,either string
>   or something that can be converted to json by jackson (Map,ArrayList)

```
@RequestMapping("deleteUserReq")
@ResponseBody
public String inactiveUserReq(@RequestParam HttpServletRequest 
request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
System.out.println("===== going to delete user ===== ");
/*String userChk=reportDAOImpl.inactiveUser(userID);*/
String userChk="success";
System.out.println("  ===  "+userChk);
//return new ModelAndView("ModifyUser","responsetxt",userChk);
//return string or json
return "success";
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Actually the URL is not hitting the controller.

Comment: The issue might be with the data you are sending ,send some dumy string data and check

Comment: I have open a popup window [ info.jsp -- URL: http://localhost:8085/CdfPortal/userModify?usrId=BU941003] in this jsp I have delete button that is calling method: deleteUser(). Now when I am submit the request to call controller: deleteUserReq. I always goes to userModify controller.

Answer (score 0):

URl is not calling deleteUserReq controller

```
http://localhost:8085/CdfPortal/userModify?usrId=BU941003 [Actual result]
http://localhost:8085/CdfPortal/deleteUserReq?usrId=BU941003 [Required]
```